# MobileIron custom configuration error : Plist not valid

Tags: ios, mobile, mobileiron

I have a MobileIron cloud instance, i want to add a custom configuration for my in house app.
I create my plist file with xCode. it has only one key value.
But when i try to add the custom configuration using my plist i get :

> configData: the suggested configuration is not valid.

Any idea where this issue may come from ?

Comment: Same question, any answer?